# Criando array a partir de outro array

Tags: javascript

```
var contatos = [
  {
    nome: 'Alex Silva Souza',
    endereco: 'Travessa 1, casa 233',
    tel: '2235-3514',
    id:1123,
    email: '****',
  },
  {
    nome: 'Beatriz Santana Pinto',
    endereco: 'Rua cardoso de moraes, casa 21',
    tel: '3448-3514',
    id:1124,
    email: 'bea_2016_rj@outlook.com'
  },
  {
    nome: 'Felippe Roger Teles',
    endereco: 'Rua Ana teles, casa 107',
    tel: '2556-1818',
    id:1125,
    email: '****'
  },
  {
    nome: 'Rogerio Machado da Silva',
    endereco: 'Rua Baronesa, 231 ap101',
    tel: '98337-3317',
    id:1126,
    email: 'rogerio.m.silva@hotmail.com'
  },
];


var identificacao = []
```

A minha intenção é colocar dentro do array identificacao apenas as propriedades nome e id. Ficaria assim :

```
var identificacao = [
  {
    nome: 'Alex Silva Souza',
    id:1123,
  },
  {
    nome: 'Beatriz Santana Pinto',
    id:1124,
  }
];
```

Mas oq estou fazendo me retorna isso:

```
var identificacao = ["Alex Silva Souza", 1123, "Beatriz Santana Pinto", 1124, "Felippe Roger Teles", 1125, "Rogerio Machado da Silva", 1126]
```

Comment: Esses emails são verdadeiros?

Comment: não kk, nenhum dado é real.

Comment: Olha que um deles existe mesmo... http://omtaram.com/rogerioemonyke

Comment: lol ... Mas com certeza os dados como endereço e nome não correspondem ao dono do email, todos os items foram inventados por mim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deves usar o [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) para mapear de um objeto para outro.

```
var subselecao = contatos.map(function(contacto) {
  return {
    nome: contacto.nome,
    id: contacto.id
  };
});
```

Um exemplo seria assim:

```js
var contatos = [{
    nome: 'Alex Silva Souza',
    endereco: 'Travessa 1, casa 233',
    tel: '2235-3514',
    id: 1123,
    email: '****',
  },
  {
    nome: 'Beatriz Santana Pinto',
    endereco: 'Rua cardoso de moraes, casa 21',
    tel: '3448-3514',
    id: 1124,
    email: 'bea_2016_rj@outlook.com'
  },
  {
    nome: 'Felippe Roger Teles',
    endereco: 'Rua Ana teles, casa 107',
    tel: '2556-1818',
    id: 1125,
    email: '****'
  },
  {
    nome: 'Rogerio Machado da Silva',
    endereco: 'Rua Baronesa, 231 ap101',
    tel: '98337-3317',
    id: 1126,
    email: 'rogerio.m.silva@hotmail.com'
  },
];

var subselecao = contatos.map(function(contacto) {
  return {
    nome: contacto.nome,
    id: contacto.id
  };
});

console.log(subselecao);
```

Em browsers modernos poderia ser:

```
const subselecao = contatos.map(({nome, id}) => ({nome, id}));
```

Comment: Nossa mano, obrigado mesmo.
Olha o que eu estava fazendo: 
contatos.map( e => identificacao.push(e.nome, e.id));

Comment: @mtAlves pois, o `map` é feito para estes casos. Fico contente de ter ajudado :)